# Filter through a Table in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a Vue app that renders a number of quotes and allows you to search through the data. I think maybe I'm not binding the function to the right element. I have a v-model attribute on the input tag so that should bind whatever text a user inputs in.

Here's my template:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Quotes</h3>
    <div class="controllers">
      <div class="search">
         <input id="search-item" type="text" placeholder="Search for a quote..." v-model="searchText"/>
         <button @click="searchResults()" class="search-btn">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Source</th>
          <th scope="col">Context</th>
          <th scope="col">Quote</th>
          <th scope="col">Theme</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="quote in quotes" v-bind:key="quote.quote"> 
          <th scope="row">{{quote.context}}</th>
          <td>{{quote.source}}</td>
          <td>{{quote.quote}}</td>
          <td>{{quote.theme}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table> 
  </div> 
</template>
```

Here's my script

```
  import axios from 'axios';
  export default {
    name: 'Quotes',
    data() {
      return {
        searchText: '',
        // search: null,
        // data: null,
        quotes: [ 
          {
            quote: null,
            context:  null,
            source: null,
            theme: null,
            currentPage: 0,
        }
        ],
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      axios
        .get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benchprep/dffc3bffa9704626aa8832a3b4de5b27/raw/quotes.json')
        .then(res => {
          this.quotes = res.data;
        })
      },
    methods: {
      searchResults() {
        if (this.searchText.length === 0) {
        return '';
      }
      return this.quotes.filter(quote => quote.quote.match(this.searchText));
     },
  }
}
```

When I try and implement a search the functionality doesn't work. I'm not getting any errors in the compiler.

Comment: `searchText` is never changed for what I see, and `v-model="filter"` is not used too, i think your error is `v-model="filter"` it should be `v-model="searchText"`

Comment: Ah yes I see that error. I just changed it `v-model="searchText" ` and I'm still not able to search through the table.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is wrong it should be:

```js
    searchResults() {
        if (this.searchText.length == 0 || this.searchText == '') return;
        this.quotes = this.quotes.filter(quote => quote.quote.match(this.searchText));
    }
```

You don't need to `return this.quotes`, you change the array instead. But this will cause to empty the array so instead you should use another variable with the original array.

This is better:

```js
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                searchText: "",
                quotes: [],
                data: [],
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            this.fetchQuotes();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchQuotes() {
                let url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benchprep/dffc3bffa9704626aa8832a3b4de5b27/raw/quotes.json/';
                axios.get(url).then(res => {
                    this.quotes = res.data;
                    this.data = res.data;
                });
            },
            searchResults() {
                if (this.searchText.length == 0 || this.searchText == '') {
                    this.quotes = this.data;
                }
                this.quotes = this.data.filter(quote => quote.quote.includes(this.searchText));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I try and assign `this.quotes` to `this.data` nothing renders on my page. But it does render without reassigning `this.quotes`

Comment: that's strange, let me see your code. I did a test in local and it works.

Comment: `fetchQuotes() {
            let url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benchprep/dffc3bffa9704626aa8832a3b4de5b27/raw/quotes.json/';
            axios.get(url).then(res => {
              this.quotes = res.data;
              this.quotes = this.data;
            });
    `

Comment: You can mark the answer if this helped you :)

Comment: Tried to but apparently I don't have enough reputations to :/

Comment: No worries!, I'm glad I can help :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the `searchResults()` function because it is only filtering `this.quotes` and return this value, but this value is not used, thus the object `this.quotes` continue with the started values. I'd suggest that you update the `this.quotes` when call the function `searchResults()` but remember to save the initial results.

The best way for this is to use a computed variable that return this.quotes filtered when needed. See in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties